# Missing detail in man/info page for unix `cut` command?

Tags: cut

I found the page [this page](http://superuser.com/questions/332356/in-linux-how-do-i-truncate-command-line-output) on truncating text using the `cut` command very helpful. The solution is `someCommand | cut -c -80`.  However, the man and info pages don't actually explain the negative sign in `-80`.  I like to be confident that I can drill down into these pages and make sense of them.  Can anyone point out where the missing detail is specified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the full man page;

-M
from first to M'th (included) byte, character or field

In your exmaple M=80.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, Jon.  Makes perfect sense now.  The information that you cited was in fact present.  I just didn't look at all the right pieces at the same time.